# Existential quantifier question $\forall x \forall y(P(x)\land P(y) \implies x=y)$

Tags: quantifiers

Quesiton about existential quantifier
The unique quantifier is $!\exists xP(x)$ so only one x is true.

And I am wondering if the following is equal to unique quantifier

$\forall x \forall y(P(x)\land P(y)) \implies x=y)$

So this is saying that for all the x and y which makes P() true then x is identical to y.
But this is equivalent to saying

$\forall x \forall y(\neg P(x)\lor \neg P(y) \lor x=y)$

And if for all x P(x) is not true then it cannot be true for one x.

Not sure if I am right.

Comment: I don't think this is right. If $P(x)$ happens to be false for all $x$, then $\exists!xP(x)$ is false but your expression would be true, as the left side of the implication would be false for all $x, y$.

Comment: Your expression seems to be equivalent to "at most one $x$ is such that $P(x)$", rather than exactly one.

Comment: It could be $\exists x(P(x)\wedge\forall y(P(y)\implies y=x))$ or you could take the conjunction of yours and $\exists xP(x)$. Or [other options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification).

Comment: Yes P(x) and P(y) could be false and implication is still true, so there might not exist an x and y which makes P() true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exists !x P(x)$ means that $P(x)$ is true for *exactly* one $x$.  Your statement $\forall x\forall y((P(x) \wedge P(y)) \to x = y)$ means that $P(x)$ is true for *at most* one $x$.  To say that $P(x)$ is true for exactly one $x$, you have to say that it is true for at least one $x$, and also at most one $x$.  So $\exists !xP(x)$ is equivalent to:
$$
\exists x P(x) \wedge \forall x\forall y((P(x) \wedge P(y)) \to x = y).
$$